# Initizlizing a DbContext in a BaseController for MVC6 and EF7?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Following the [ASP.Net 5 Getting Started](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5/new-db.html) document I see that because of `dependency injection` at the top of any controller that will access the database I need to put something like

```
private DbContext _Context;

public HomeController(DbContext Context)
{
      _Context = Context;
}
```

to inject the DbContext into the controller for use. In my ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 Web App every single page will be interacting with the database so I thought I would create a `BaseController` that the reset of my controllers would inherit from and put the injection code there. I have done this but every controller that inherits from the `BaseController` give me the error

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Context' of 'BaseController.BaseController(DbContext)

I am new to DI and not sure if I am doing things right or even if it can be done the way I want to. Is it possible to do it this way or do I have to put that code on every controller I make, and if I do have to do that how can I write an action in the `BaseController` that interacts with the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your base controller has a constructor that takes DbContext then any controller that inherits it must also use the same constructor like this so it can pass the dependency to the base class:

```
public HomeController(DbContext Context):base(Context)
{

}
```

Comment: I added your code and the error went away but I doing `_DbContext` is not accessible from the `HomeController`

Comment: you need to declare as protected in the base controller so that homecontroller is allowed to use it.

Comment: myself, I would recommend against using a basecontroller like that and I would not use dbcontext directly by a controller. Instead I would have some service class that wraps the dbContext and exposes the methods needed by the controllers for data operations without giving direct access to the dbcontext. So the controllers would need the service class injected and the service class would need the dbcontext injected into it.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, I do not have much exposure beyond what I have learned in my own projects and just a few years of being a jr. developer. And DI is completely new to me until I started working with .Net 5 a month ago.

Comment: the basecontroller is not providing any benefit unless it has other functions since the derived controllers all still need to depend on the dbcontext. It is better to have an abstraction layer between the UI (controllers) and the data layer instead of using dbcontext directly

Comment: I can show you examples in my projects, [here is a controller for managing geographic data](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Controllers/CoreDataController.cs) instead of having direct access to dbcontext it has a dependency on [GeoDataManager](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Components/GeoDataManager.cs) which depends on IGeoRepository [implemented here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Repositories.EF/GeoRepository.cs) which has the dbcontext

Comment: you can also find where each of those dependencies is registered with DI services [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/example.WebApp/Startup.CloudscribeCore.DI.MS.cs)

Comment: The BaseController does have other methods that need to be ran/accessible from all controllers. When you say an abstraction layer are you talking about Data Transfer Objects? I remember reading about those a while back as a way to move data from DB to controller and I remember the examples having methods to get/change data in them